# Need to have the correct url path in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get my Django app to point to the correct URL in my chatserver/urls.py file.

I am getting this error when I start my django app:

> Using the URLconf defined in chatserver.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ join [name='join'] The empty path didn’t match any of these.

This is my chatserver/urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('chat.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And this is my chat/urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('join', views.init, name='join'),
]
```

And here is my app project directory:

[image: directory structure]

How can I correct my error?

Comment: You don't have any path that points to the empty path.  You may think you do with `path('', include('chat.urls')),`, but that will include `path('join', views.init, name='join'),` to the path, so that the correct path would be something like, `127.0.0.1/join`.  If you want the empty path then you need to change your chat/urls.py path to `path('', views.init, name='join'),`

Comment: @raphael that appeared to work.  
I got a jason response back saying: " {
"message": "No request body"
}"

Comment: I'd need to see your views.py, and template at the very least to even try to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide a name for my app in chat/urls.py

```
from .views import init

app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('join', view=init, name='join'),
]
```

then for my chatserver/urls.py provide a namespace for each path

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('chat.urls', namespace='chat')),
]
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatserver.chat'

Comment: In your chatserver/urls.py remove "chatserver" from the include method, and only use "chat.urls", also make sure the chat app is added to INSTALL_APP in settings.py

Comment: @iJermaine: I have chat in my seetings.py file in INSTALL_APP section

Comment: your solution @Jermaine still give me an error. It doesn't know what to do with the from chatserver.chat.views import init declaration.

Comment: I see, I edited my initial answer to match your code style. Its now "from .views import init"